# PHP 7 on IIS: Call_user_function could not be located

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I am trying to use the Microsoft SQL Server drivers with PHP 7.1 Not Thread Safe x64 on Windows 2012 R2 64-bit server.

No matter what I do I am getting an error when I run php from a admin command prompt

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll' - The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

Additionally it display a windows pop up that states

> The procedure entry point call_user_function could not be located in
>   the dynamic link library C:\PHP7\ext\php_pdo_dqlsrv7_nts_x64.dll

I have verified that the php.ini is pointing to a file that exists, because if I rename the .dll file, the error messages changes to "specified module could not be found", instead of specified procedure.

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ runtime 15 x64 as required by PHP 7.

I have installed Microsoft ODBC driver 13 as required by the Microsoft SQL Server driver.

I have rebooted the server twice.

There is nothing else I can think to even try. The Microsoft WinCache.dll is loading and working fine in PHP, as verified by phpinfo.

Comment: I'm also getting near same errors on my Win10 box trying to get PHP 7.3.10 to use redis v3.1.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirmed what @MEmerson said above. You need to downgrade PHP to 7.0.X(?) - I used 7.0.12.

Complete Setup:

- Windows 10 Pro
- PHP X64 7.0.12 TS (Bitnami WAMP Stack)
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703139(v=sql.1).aspx)
- Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server 4.0 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Same drivers with PHP X64 7.1.0 produced the error you are getting.

Comment: Good for Windows 8.1 also.

Answer (score 9):

[Microsoft Drivers 4.3 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642) are now available.
These drivers contains files for PHP 7.1  - php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll etc.
I've successfully managed to connect to SQL server.

Comment: [Microsoft Drivers 5.3 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57163) for PHP 7.2 - php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll

Answer (score 2):

Had similar error when tried to use httpd (Apache), PHP 7.2.2, Microsoft ODBC driver 11 on MS Windows Server 2012. The text of error was:

> The procedure entry point call_user_function could not be located in the dynamic link library php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll.

when I called `php -m` to check modules.

So I have downloaded Windows-7.2.zip from https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases and used thread-safe dlls from it.

`php -m` works now as it should without giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Same as NoCopy

- Windows Server 2012
- php-7.0.15-Win32-VC14-x64.zip from (http://windows.php.net/download)
- Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server
- Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server 4.0

7.1.x still a No,NO from Microsoft

Comment: Please explain a bit more what your solution is about

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today while enabling the extensions in the IIS, where I by mistake enabled different versions for pdo & driver extensions (E.g. `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll` for PHP 7.0 & `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x86.dll` for PHP 7.2).

Usually the package that you download from Microsoft that contains Microsoft Drivers 5.3 for PHP for SQL Server has all the PHP extensions versions. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57163

Just make sure you enable both extensions for the same versions to avoid that error.