# connecting PHP to MSSQL error

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

I'm currently trying to connect to a MSSQL database, but from what i've read so far, there are actually extensions and files that i need to download from microsoft itself which i've went and download it here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

The error that i'm receiving currently receiving is the following.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5`

As far as i understand, i know that i'm supposed to append some extensions into the php.ini located in my xampp\php\php.ini file. However, even after appending the file from microsoft, i still can't seem to get connected.

I heard some people mentioned that the php version that i'm using which is currently `PHP Version 7.1.1` has some issues connecting back to MSSQL databases but i'm not entirely sure.

Would someone be able to point me to right direction? i've tried looking up and down appending different files into the extension but i still can't seem to do it.

Thank you very much in advance.

edit:

[PHP 7 on IIS: Call_user_function could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068570/php-7-on-iis-call-user-function-could-not-be-located)

i've also visited this link, however i'm unsure whether if this is related to the issue I have as i'm on 7.1