# The procedure entry point _zend_hash_index_update@@24 could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: php, sql-server, driver, php-7.3

When I start XAMPP it gives me the following error when trying to load the SQL Server driver for PHP.

> The procedure entry point _zend_hash_index_update@@24 could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll.

I have tried downloading both the Microsoft SQL Server Driver 4.0 and 5.6 for php and use the php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll and php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll in the extension directory and add them to php.ini.

I found this posting related to this error:

[PHP 7 on IIS: Call_user_function could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068570/php-7-on-iis-call-user-function-could-not-be-located)

In the system requirements, for MSSQL driver 4.0 it states that this driver is good for PHP 7.0+. In trying 5.6, I found this posting saying that it's support for PHP 7.3:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2019/03/01/drivers-5-6-for-php-for-sql-server-released/

Either way, I still receive the same error. Is there something else I need to be checking?

Comment: goto "https://xdebug.org/download" and download dll according to your php version.

Answer (score 3):

In short go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017#php-version-support.

Then compare your php version against driver version in a table displayed.

Finally download a correct version, that is all.

Answer (score 2):

**use the 7.3 one instead** (`php_sqlsrv_73_...`)

I was receiving this error also, trying to load `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86` for `php-7.3.8-nts-Win32-VC15-x86`.

[image]

If you look at [this support matrix on the microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017#php-version-support) you'll see plenty of other options for drivers that support your PHP version.

I downloaded the latest, [the SQLSRV561 package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57916). That did the trick.

**So Just to be clear,**

I loaded `php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll` (from SQLSRV5.6.EXE) instead of  `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86` (from SQLSRV4.0.EXE), and that fixed the problem.